# How to ask the user for confirmation of an action with a popup box?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net

I'm currently coding a button which will delete a record from a database if clicked. However, I want some sort of confirmation after they click it so there are no accidents. I was imagining a popup box that tells them they are about to delete this record with two buttons cancel and OK. If cancelled, nothing happens, but if OK is pressed, then the server would execute the delete as coded. How would I do this in asp/vb?

Comment: Oh there surely will be accidents. If the user clicked the button by accident, he will get confused and click through your dialog by accident...

Comment: The underlying JavaScript function that you want is `confirm("orly?");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a button with a confirmation message :

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" 
     OnClick="btnDelete_Click" 
     OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete the record ? ');" />
```

Here is the way to add confirm client script at server side :

```
btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
        "return confirm('Do you want to delete the record ? ');")
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. For a little bit I was confused as to how to do an if statement with the confirm, but I see how it's handled now, I was just making it more complex than it is. Thanks again.

Comment: Wich is the best way ?

Answer (score 0):

[Adding Client-Side Message Boxes in your ASP.NET Web Pages](https://web.archive.org/web/20210416025953/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021104-1.aspx) is a great tutorial to make client-side confirmation messages like this:

[image]

Using ASP.NET & VB.NET (Don't forget to read part2.)